# Mocking context in node.js using express and azure mobile apps for Mocha testing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocking, mocha.js

I have an express app running as an Azure Mobile app.

This has a bunch of api methods that are fairly straightforward and just read from a sql database.

For example - this is what one looks like (Things.js):

```
var logger = require('../logger/logger.js')

module.exports = {
    get: function(req, res, next){
        var context = req.azureMobile;
        var id =  req.query.id ;
        if(!id){
            logger.info("ID is blank or empty")
            res.status(400).send("ID is blank or empty");
        }else{
            context.tables('Things')
            .where({ ThingId: id })
            .read()
            .then(function (things) {
                if(things.length === 1)
                    res.status(200).send();
                else
                    res.status(404).send("Thing not found");
            })
            .catch(next); 
        }
    }
}
```

It tells us if an id exists in the database.

This is clean and straightforward. I've written some tests (ThingsTests.js):

```
var assert = require('assert');
var httpMocks = require('node-mocks-http');
var things = require('../../api/Things');

describe('Things', function() {
  describe('get', function() {
    it('should return status 400 when the value does not exist', function() {
      //Arrange
      var req = httpMocks.createRequest();
      var res = httpMocks.createResponse();
      //Act
      things.get(req, res)
      //Assert
      assert.equal(400, res.statusCode);
    });

    it('should return status 400 when the thing id does not exist', function() {
      //Arrange
      var req = httpMocks.createRequest();
      var res = httpMocks.createResponse();
      req.query.id = "1234";

      //How do I set up a mock of the context here?

      //Act
      things.get(req, res);
      //Assert
      assert.equal(400, res.statusCode);
    });
  });
});
```

The first test passes ok, but the second test fails because it cannot understand the context. The error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'tables' of undefined
```

I understand why that is.

I'm mostly from a C# background so I understand the concept of mocking (I use Moq normally). What I can't figure out is how to mock the context here to return a dataset. Does anyone know?